# How can I use newer release of android databinding library?

Tags: android

according to the bintray, newer version of the Android Databinding library has been [released](https://bintray.com/search?query=databinding+android)(1.0-rc5).

but if I'm correct, only compiler, compilerCommon and baseLibrary are updated, and dataBinder(which we actually include in build.gradle) is still 1.0-rc4.

Is there a way to use newer compiler, compilerCommon and baseLibrary while using dataBinder 1.0-rc4? Or is there already a 1.0-rc5 for dataBinder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, in Android gradle plugin 1.5.0-beta1, dev team integrated data binding plugin into android plugin.

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system

Answer (score 2):

You can override the data-binding version in the build.gradle, like this:

```
dataBinding {
    enabled true
    version '1.1'
}
```